# How to update Twitter profile picture using twitter api and data:image/gif;base64?

Tags: php, twitter, yahoo-pipes

> iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAAlwSFlzAAALEwAACxMBAJqcGAAAAAd0SU1FB9YGARc5KB0XV+IAAAAddEVYdENvbW1lbnQAQ3JlYXRlZCB3aXRoIFRoZSBHSU1Q72QlbgAAAF1JREFUGNO9zL0NglAAxPEfdLTs4BZM4DIO4C7OwQg2JoQ9LE1exdlYvBBeZ7jqch9//q1uH4TLzw4d6+ErXMMcXuHWxId3KOETnnXXV6MJpcq2MLaI97CER3N0vr4MkhoXe0rZigAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==

The above data is a picture in `data:image/png;base64` format.
Is it possible to update a twitter profile picture without providing the path to the image (like http://....com) but instead by providing the image data in the format above?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's documented https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/account/update_profile_image and https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/account/update_profile_background_image

Sending something via `base64_encode(file_get_contents($image_path))))` will yield results. Make sure your file is <700kb and smaller than <1000px.

Answer (score 0):

Having had a quick look at the Twitter Documentation, specifically the section regarding [Updating a User's Profile Image](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method%3A-account%C2%A0update_profile_image), it does not clearly state whether it will, or will not accept a Base64-encoded string for an image.

That being said, I would presume that it would not (feel free to test it and see if it does, but, as a rule, if an API wants a URL as an input, it will only recognise a URL as valid).

You could, of course, create a PHP script on your server, which, using the PHP function `imagecreatefromstring()`[[PHP Docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php)] and then use that URI as the value for the Twitter API.